# How to access QML Singleton from javascript .js file?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

How can javascript in a separate **.js** file access a QML singleton?

My javascript library wants to read configuration values stored in a singleton which is defined in **TrConfig.qml**:

```
// TrConfig.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQml 2.0

QtObject {
  property var myWidth: 234
}
```

The **qmldir** file contains

```
singleton TrConfig 1.0 TrConfig.qml
```

This works fine from inside .qml files by simply referencing `TrConfig.<fieldname>`.  But in .js files after `.import TrConfig as TC`, referencing `TC.<fieldname>` always returns undefined.

```
// myjslib.js
.import QtQml 2.11 as QtQml
.import TrConfig as TC

function myfunc() {
  console.log("In myjslib.js myWidth is " + TC.myWidth); 
  // prints "... myWidth is undefined"
}
```

Here is the main .qml file (run with "qml Foo.qml"):

```
// Foo.qml
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls 
import "myjslib.js" as J

Rectangle {
  width: TrConfig.myWidth // this works
  height: 100
  color: "red"
  
  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("Foo onCompleted: myWidth="+TrConfig.myWidth);
    J.myfunc();
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
qml: Foo onCompleted: myWidth=234
qml: In myjslib.js myWidth is undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Updated 11/6/21 to add ".import TrConfig as TC" into the .js file]

Comment: Aren't you missing an `.import TrConfig as TrConfig`?

Comment: @Mitch thanks.  I added that and updated the description.   But now, instead of a compiler error, the run-time always retrieves "undefined" from any field in the singleton.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Is there some documentation or other reason why you think this should be possible in the way you have implemented it? I've seen other ways of doing this, but not in this manner.

Comment: Please see the last paragraph at the bottom of https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-imports.html which specifically mentions accessing a singleton type from a "JavaScript Resource" (which AFAIK means a .js file).


BTW I tried `import "myjslib.js" 1.0 as J` and that doesn't seem to work either, and no error occurs if the "1.0" is replaced by a higher, i.e. non-existent number like 2.0